# Getting a list of manufacturers from a database

Tags: php, performance, mysql, zend-framework

I'm new to Zend Framework. Can you help me optimize this function, which gets a list of `Manufactures` with some conditions from a database?

```
private function Manufactures(
    $Condition = array(),
    $Order = array('name' => 'ASC'),
    $Strict = TRUE,
    $Limit = NULL)
{
    $Request = $this->_DbTable->select();
    $Clause  = $Strict ? '=' : 'LIKE';
    foreach ($Condition as $index => $value) {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            $Request->where($this->_DbTable->info('name') . '.' . $index . ' '. $Clause .' ?', $value);
        } else {
            foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
                if (is_array($val)) {
                    foreach ($val as $valIndex) {
                        if (isset($valIndex['modifier']) && isset($valIndex['value'])) {
                            $Request->where($this->_DbTable->info('name') . '.' . $key . ' ' . $valIndex['modifier']. ' ?', $valIndex['value']);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($Order as $index => $value) {
        $Request->order($index . ' ' . $value);
    }
    if($Limit) $Request->limit($Limit);
    $Data = $this->_DbTable->fetchAll($Request)
                           ->toArray();
    return isset($Data) ? $Data : NULL;
}
```